# Calculate the diagonal of a big.matrix in R

Tags: r, bigdata, diagonal, r-bigmemory

I am working with several big squared matrices of 1.3e6 rows, and I want to the diagonal of all of them. I need an efficient way to do it, but I can not use diag()

```
library(bigmemory)
A=big.matrix(nrow=1.3e6,ncol=1.3e6,init=3)
diag(A)
```

Any idea?
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Not a full solution, but could you split this matrix up (then use normal matrix notation) or does that not work for your analysis? For example A=matrix(3, nrow=1.3e6/100,ncol=1.3e6/100)
diag(A) then loop this 100 times.

Comment: Do you really have a 1,300,000 x 1,300,000 `big.matrix`? An effecient way to get the diagonal would be to implement it in Rcpp. But, I think there is something else going on here..

Comment: I only want an efficient way to extract the diagonal of the matrix. I have seen that in Rcpp package there is a function call cppFunction to call C++, and  that Li Zeng in https://zenglix.github.io/Rcpp_basic/  uses the "diagmat" function from arma::vec to extract the diagonal of the matrix. But, I don´t know how to call it with cppFunction

Comment: cppFunction('NumericVector diagC(NumericMatrix x) {
  int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out(nrow);
 out=diagmat( x );
 
  return out;
}',depends=arma::vec::iterator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in fact, you don't need Rcpp here.
Just use the special matrix accessor of two-columns:

```
library(bigmemory)

X <- big.matrix(10, 10); X[] <- 1:100

d <- min(dim(X))
X[cbind(1:d, 1:d)]
```

`X[cbind(1:d, 1:d)]` will access `X[1, 1]`, `X[2, 2]`, ..., `X[d, d]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. it workds and I have checked with library profvis and the performance of this code is pretty good.